# How to transfer Control back to the previous form?

Tags: qt, qt-creator

I am new to Qt.

I am doing a project using Qt Creator. In my project, I have one mainWindow. From the main window I start 4 screens (one after another, showing Initialization process). A new QDialog screen is opened, if there are any errors on any screen. My error screens have two Button (Retry, Continue). If i press Retry, i have to restart the initialization process over again.
eg;

```
void ErrorScreen1::on_Retry_pressed()
{
    Screen1 *scrn = new Screen1(this); 
    scrn->show();
    this->close();
}
```

In above example, it restarts the process.

Is there any way, I can start the initialization process from the point it was left?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this issue by using QMessageBox as my error window.

It allowed me to start my process from the point i left.

```
void Screen1::ErrorMessage()
{
    timer->stop();

    QMessageBox *msgbox = new QMessageBox(this);
    msgbox->setWindowTitle("ERROR MESSAGE");
    msgbox->setText("Initialization Failed.");
    msgbox->setStandardButtons(QMessageBox::Cancel | QMessageBox::Retry);
    msgbox->setDefaultButton(QMessageBox::Retry);

    int ret = msgbox->exec();

    switch (ret)
    {
        case QMessageBox::Retry: timer->start(); break;

        case QMessageBox::Cancel:
            timer->disconnect();
            ui->progressBar->setValue(0);
            break;

        default: break;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In common you should somehow keep the current state of your process and then you can restore it.

Comment: Thanks hank,
It means i need to use flag to monitor the status.
I was wondering, if Qt has some inbuilt logic for doing so.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered making those four dialogs into a wizard with four steps?  The next button could work for the continue, and you could have a retry button on each page that it makes sense, with just that page doing the retry logic necessary.

Comment: Thanks Caleb,
I have 4 screens having initialization process with its 4 error screen. Error screen have 2 pushbutton "RETRY" & "Continue". I wish that if RETRY is pressed it should start from the state it was left.

Yes, i tried making 4 wizards but again i did'nt get any perfect logic to do so.